# is my way to prove its tautology correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

this equation solved by me but I don't think its correct, so is there anyone can show me the mistakes ?

(p>q)^(q>r)>(p>r)

(p v -q)^(q v -r) v- (p v -r)

p^q v p^-r v T v -q^-r v -p^r

T v -p^r

T^r

Comment: $p \to q$ is $\lnot p \lor q$ and the same for the others.

Comment: sorry, can u explain it to me

Comment: What rule have you used in step 1 ? The "usual" way to remove $\to$ is to use [Material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)).

Comment: the same role u suggest but I mistook the placement of the -ve sign

Comment: Yes, it is wrong because you ended with r instead of T.   To easily show it is a tautology, use truth tables.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the premise:  (p > q)&(q > r).
If p, then by p > q, q and since q, then by q > r, r.
Thus p > r.
This sketch can be formalized using the turnstile notation |-
which is more efficient than creating a series of equivalent statements.